# Existing Symfony project and confusing composer.json packages need different versions of Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to extend an existing Symfony application, but the composer.json doesn't make any sense.

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.1.*"
```

Results in an error because 2.1.* is not a resolvable version number this would indicate that the programmer hasn't bothered to update the file or use it.

Then I try it by changing it to:

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.1.12"
```

It then fails because:

```
mopa/bootstrap-bundle dev-master requires symfony/symfony ~2.3-dev 
jms/di-extra-bundle 1.1.0-RC requires symfony/framework-bundle 2.1.*
```

This would suggest I can either install bootstrap or jms because one requires symfony 2.1 and the other 2.3 but in the composer.phar I see:

```
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
```

In the production server I see that vendor has a jsm and mopa sub directory and under vendor/symfony/symfony the highest changelog I can find is CHANGELOG-2.1.md suggesting that some version of Symfony 2.1 is used (only have ftp access so can't run a command to check the version).

I wonder how I can get this installed because it just quits every time on the Symfony version not getting resolved.

The other thing is; should I resolve this. If one of these packages don't run because of a wrong Symfony version that what's the point of installing it in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating from a previous version of symfony you had to update all dependeciens. So looking https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v2.1.11/composer.json you have to set:

```
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.5-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev"
```

and looking for MopaBootstrapBundle on packagist (https://packagist.org/packages/mopa/bootstrap-bundle) the last version that support Symfony 2.1 is:

`"mopa/bootstrap-bundle": "2.2.*@dev"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have deleted the vendor directory and composer.lock. Removed mopa from composer.json and it's installing now. When it's done I'll try to add mopa again with version `2.2-dev` I guess at the time of writing the json `dev-master` was fine but since mopa 2.3 doesn't work with symfony 2.1.* it's causing a problem now. Thank you again for your help, I am just now using composer so having a little trouble figuring it out. Will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: It did install everything except twitter bootstrap but after all is done and I try to open a page all I get is: `Unable to load class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\PhpBridgeSessionStorage` and indeed the file PhpBridgeSessionStorage doesn't exist in the Storage directory. Will try to figure this one out now.

Comment: Do you refresh the cache? Where is the class called?

Comment: I deleted the cache and was on the the next error in app/config/config.yml the entries `fragments:` and `http_method_override: true` under framework caused an error so I removed them. And on the next error. The sql script that supposedly creates the tables doesn't create all the tables so tried to run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` getting an error `Can't create table 'truck.#sql-3b4_1d' (errno: 150)` Not sure what #sql-3b4_1d is because a `grep -r "3b4" .` gives me zero files.

Comment: Solved the last one by dropping all the tables and have doctrine create them. Now to see if I can make the requested changes. All these tools are great if they work and with a little nudge they do seem to work. composer, doctrine it's like magic.